# Text File Attached to Email Sent with Python is Blank

Tags: python, email, smtp, pydev, email-attachments

I'm creating a program that creates a text file, then sends an email with the text file as an attachment. Right now, when I create the text file, it works perfectly, and the text file contains everything I need. However, when I send the email, the attachment I get is a blank text file of the same name. Here is my code that creates the attachment and sends the email:

```
    def email(self, filename):
        attachment = open(filename, "rb")
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
        msg.attach(part)    #the msg here is created earlier in the code with the body
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        server.login(fromAddr, "password")
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(fromAddr, (toAddr, ccAddr), text)
        server.quit()
        attachment.close()
```

I don't see anything in the code that would cause the attachment to be blank, so any help would be greatly appreciated. If there are any typos in the code above, I'm sorry. I don't think those are the problems though as I'm not getting any syntax errors in my code.

Additional info: I am coding this in Eclipse using PyDev.
The part where I actually create the message is below, in case that makes a difference.

```
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromAddr
    msg['To'] = toAddr
    msg['Cc'] = ccAddr
    msg['Subject'] = "This is the subject field for the email"
    body = "This is the text that is in the body of the email."
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
```

UPDATE: I might have figured out what is going on. The file that I was sending was very small (right around 1K), so I think that the system I'm on was thinking it was spam and erasing everything in it. When I upped the size of the file (anywhere over 4K) it would send the attachment and it had info. However, I am now running into a new problem in that some of my info in the attachment is getting deleted. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason as to where it is getting cut off. Sometimes, only a few lines get cut off, but other times I'm losing around a quarter of my data. What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. I was reading the file into the attachment before I was finished writing the file. If this happens to anyone else, make sure you close your file you are writing to before you read from it to make the attachment.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see that could potentially be causing the problem is the line:

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
```

Try it like this instead:

```
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename)
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, but the same thing happened. The file was created, and the email was sent, but the attachment was empty (0K).

Comment: I figured it out. I was reading the file into the attachment before the file was done being written. Thanks for your help anyways.